# Modified Euler Method for second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The question I am doing is asking me to carry out the Modified Euler method for a second order differential equation:

> Consider the following initial value problem: 
>   $$y''=\frac{2}{x}y'-\frac{2}{x^2} y - \frac{1}{x^2},\quad y(1)=0, \quad y'(1)=1$$
>   Calculate the numerical solution at $x=1.2$ using the modified Euler's method. Take the step length $h=0.2$ and work to $6$ decimal digit accuracy.

So far whilst studying ODEs I have only come across numerical methods for **first order** differential equations. How do I go about solving this?

Usually, $f(x,y) = y'$ but  what does $f(x,y)$ equal this time?

Comment: Were you able to use the answer to resolve your problem?

Comment: Not quite - it was useful but it didn't resolve my problem. Hence why I haven't accepted it as an answer just yet.

Comment: I added an answer to add more details, see if that helps. Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As lhf mentioned, we need to write this as a system of first order equations and then we can use Euler's Modified Method (EMM) on the system.

We can follow this procedure to write the second order equation as a first order system. Let $w_1(x) = y(x)$, $w_2(x) = y'(x)$, giving us:

- $w'_1 = y' = w_2$
- $w'_2 = y'' = \left(\dfrac{2}{x}\right)w_2 -\left(\dfrac{2}{x^2}\right)w_1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2}$

Our initial conditions become:

$$w_1(1) = 0, w_2(1) = 1$$

Now, you can apply EMM and you can see how you step through that (only Euler method, but it will give you the approach) at [*The Euler Method for Higher Order Differential Equations*](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/NumericInt/Euler2.html)

From the given conditions, we are only doing one step of the algorithm, since we are starting at $x=1$ and want to find the result at $x=1.2$, where $h=0.2$.

Also note, we can compare the numerical solution to the exact result, which is:

$$y(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x^2-1\right)$$

That should be enough to guide you.

Comment: Needs another TU! $\small{+1}$

Comment: Hey, you capped for the day. Congrats! (As Asaf commented to me when I was approaching the 20k threshold: "I feel I can almost trust you!")

Comment: Yes, indeed, in fact, you can still earn a few more points that count. Capping is officially when you've received 200 points from upvotes alone, within a Math.SE day, such that no more reputation points can be earned from additional upvotes, (but the votes themselves "stand"). For example, I've "capped", and will not earn any more points today (until 5 pm your time), unless those points come from "accepts".

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a second-order equation, you need to pack $u=(y,y')$ and then write $u'=(y',y'')=(y',f(x,y))=g(x,u)$.

Answer (score 0):

use y'=z and y''=z' and then solve both equation simultaneously